# I need to use my drones camera instead of my webcam

Tags: java, eclipse, opencv

I am trying to use my drones camera instead of my webcam. I am using the YADrone API and OpenCV in java in Eclipse.

```
package Drone;
import java.awt.Image;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.videoio.VideoCapture;
import org.opencv.videoio.Videoio;

import de.yadrone.base.IARDrone;    

public class Video{

static {
    System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
}

private JFrame frame;
private JLabel imageLabel;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Video app = new Video();
    app.initGUI();
    IARDrone drone = null;
    app.runMainLoop(args, drone);
}

private void initGUI() {
    frame = new JFrame("Camera Input Example");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(700, 450);
    imageLabel = new JLabel();
    frame.add(imageLabel);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

private void runMainLoop(String[] args, final IARDrone drone) {
    ImageProcessor imageProcessor = new ImageProcessor();
    Mat camMatImage = new Mat();
    Image tempImage;
    VideoCapture capture = new VideoCapture(0);
    capture.set(Videoio.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 800);
    capture.set(Videoio.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 800);
    if (capture.isOpened()) {
        while (true) {
            capture.read(camMatImage);
            if (!camMatImage.empty()) {
                tempImage = imageProcessor.toBufferedImage(camMatImage);
                ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(tempImage, "Captured video");
                imageLabel.setIcon(imageIcon);
                frame.pack(); // this will resize the window to fit the
                                // image
            } else {
                System.out.println(" -- Frame not captured -- Break!");
                break;
            }
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("Couldn't open capture.");
    }
}
}
```

While connected to the drone (Parrot AR 2.0) via wifi it still targets my webcam on my laptop. How should i target the drones camera instead of the webcam on my laptop? Any help will be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: VideoCapture(0) opens the default camera. Try with other device id, or with the proper connection string

Answer (score 0):

here you have an example in NodeJs. https://github.com/paulhayes/copterface
The main idea is to capture the video with the API (`Node Ar Drone` in this case), and send the image frame to `OpenCV`. In your case, you would need to use an api to access the drone camera in `Java` and then send it to your `OpenCV` code.
You can use AR DRone APi from [developer.parrot.com](http://developer.parrot.com)